# Firebase Database Rules are not working in Root/childs with timestamps

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp, rules

I have a Firebase Database like this:

```
"Teilnehmer_Positions" : {
    "user_30OMH3jdfjkd3gd23sdf" : {
      ".priority" : "u1np1kz119",
      "g" : "u1np1kz119",
      "l" : [ 51.8000, 8.50000 ],
      "timestamp" : 1405704395231
    },
    "user_30OMH3jdf3dsdg23sdf" : {
      ".priority" : "u1npct5jq6",
      "g" : "u1npct5jq6",
      "l" : [ 52.0000, 8.40000],
      "timestamp" : 1705704395231
    }
}
```

I want to read Entrys in which the last update is 10 minutes ago.

Firebase Doku says:

```
// only messages from the last ten minutes can be read
        ".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 600000)",
```

So I build my Rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
    "Teilnehmer_Positions" : {
        "$users_id" : {
            ".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 600000)"
        }
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, my query shows nothing.

If I add an timestamp to my Parent it works (and show all of my data):

```
"Teilnehmer_Positions" : {
    "timestamp" : 1705704395231,
    "user_30OMH3jdfjkd3gd23sdf" : {
      ".priority" : "u1np1kz119",
      "g" : "u1np1kz119",
      "l" : [ 51.8000, 8.50000 ],
      "timestamp" : 1405704395231
    },
    "user_30OMH3jdf3dsdg23sdf" : {
      ".priority" : "u1npct5jq6",
      "g" : "u1npct5jq6",
      "l" : [ 52.0000, 8.40000],
      "timestamp" : 1705704395231
    }
```

}

So I think I have an error in my child root:

```
"Teilnehmer_Positions" : {
  "$users_id" : {
    ".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 600000)"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Post the code for your query. Also note that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters).

Comment: I have no code for this Question. My Android Code gets all of this data, but i wanna only read entrys where the timestamp is > currentTime - 10minutes. I've undstand "// only messages from the last ten minutes can be read" that with this rule my script only read this rows